# .NET Core - Hook incoming request with a Request-Id to outbound HTTP requests

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

We are looking a way to HOOK a `Request-Id` (or a `Correlation-Id`) across multiple API requests as shown figure below:

[image]

The idea is to a have one single id to trace a particular request through multiple APIs in our Logs. We are using standard `ILogger` that comes out of the box with .NET Core 2.1.

**What we have tried so far**

- We have tried using `Request-Id` in the request header, which logs successfully but we are unable to retrieve the value to add it to the subsequent HTTP request to other APIs.
- We have noticed that there is also a `CorrelationId` that gets logged. However, we are not able to figure out how to update it.
- Also, we have noticed there is `TraceIdentity` available on `HttpContextAccessor` which could potentially solve our purpose. But, we do not know how to leverage it to solve our problem.

We cannot use Application Insights and want to rely on our own logging infrastructure framework. We cannot find anything much in the documentation.

Is there any out-of-box solution available which we can use without coming up with our own custom solution?

Comment: why can´t you retrieve the value of the Request-Id header? If an incoming request has set the header Request-Id, asp.net core uses its value as CorrelationId in log messages. this is done automatically.

Comment: The requestId that gets logged is the TraceIdentifier

Comment: Hi @Jehof as mentioned, we could not find a way to retrieve the `request-id` in the subsequent requests. Could you direct us to a sample code to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I raised the same question to @davidfowl on Twitter. He has replied with:

> No there's nothing out of the box for this. There's an end to end that
>   works with app insights but it isn't very fleshed out. You might
>   consider just using the same middleware across teams.
>   if
>   There's a work item to address this in 3.0 https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1350

So, from what it looks like that for now a custom middleware is the only way forward. This may change with future release.

**Update**

We ended-up creating a custom middleware as @DavidMcEleney had suggested. However, on top of it we added the `CorrelationId` to a `AsyncLocal` property. This helped us to access the `CorrelationId` anywhere in the code if/when required. Here is the code get/set `CorrelationId`:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public static class CorrelationContext
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<string> CorrelationId = new AsyncLocal<string>();

    public static void SetCorrelationId(string correlationId)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(correlationId))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(correlationId), "Correlation id cannot be null or empty");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CorrelationId.Value))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Correlation id is already set");
        }

        CorrelationId.Value = correlationId;
    }

    public static string GetCorrelationId()
    {
        return CorrelationId.Value;
    }
}
```

To use in `CorrelationMiddleware.cs`

```
public class CorrelationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CorrelationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Correlation-Id-Header", out var correlationIds);

        var correlationId = correlationIds.FirstOrDefault() ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        CorrelationContext.SetCorrelationId(correlationId);

        using (LogContext.PushProperty("Correlation-Id", correlationId))
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

If we need to access the `CorrelationId` in anywhere in the code later, then we simply call: `CorrelationContext.GetCorrelationId();`

Comment: Yap, I have seen that. Thanks again.

Comment: please also check another free lib: https://github.com/albumprinter/CorrelationTracking/wiki

Comment: Hi @AnkitVijay
I know this question is one year old, but I was wondering:
Why you chose to go with creating a static function and not register a
a service per request, holding the value ?
It would be available to all other services through DI and, it seems to me, that the whole
`AsyncLocal` complexity would be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using Serilog for logging in dotnet core & have been pushing LogContext properties using middleware -

CorrelationMiddleware.cs

```
    public class CorrelationMiddleware
    {
    readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CorrelationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(Headers.Correlation, out StringValues correlationId);

        using (LogContext.PushProperty("Correlation-Id", correlationId.FirstOrDefault()))
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Register this in your Startup.cs Configure method:

```
app.UseMiddleware<CorrelationLogger>();
```

Then, when making an outbound http call - you can add a header to the HttpRequestMessage by adding

```
request.Headers.Add(Headers.Correlation, GetHeader("Correlation-Id"));
```

When searching logs, we can then search by the correlation id & see the full end to end between all APIs...

Comment: Hi @David we can certainly use this approach and this is the fallback option. But we wanted to avoid this since the API services could have different team owners. Instead of creating our own "custom" middleware we were looking something out of the box that can be consistent across different teams and more of a "standard" coming out of *official* ASP.NET Core SDK. Hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if this is directly related, but we face same kind of issue for correlating request across apis and services in Service Fabric projects. We ended up setting and getting correlationId from CallContext (inside System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging). 
Coincidentally just wrote something about it [here](https://vivekkhareblog.wordpress.com/2018/09/14/distributed-tracing-in-service-fabric-using-correlationid/). Please see if this helps.