# Log REST-requests to file with unique request-id

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-core, logging

Lets say I have a simple REST-API written in .net 6 which logs to a log-file on the lokal disk. During the processing of the request, multiple log-entries are generated. For example, let's say we have a controller, which calls a service, which calls a repository which stores the passed data in the database:

```cs
public class FooController {
    [HttpPost]
    public Foo CreateFoo(FooDto fooDto) {
        _logger.Debug("Some logging in the controller");
        var foo = _mapper.Map<IFoo>(fooDto);
        _fooService.CreateFoo(foo);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class FooService {
    public void CreateFoo(IFoo foo) {
        _logger.Debug("Some logging in the service");
        _fooRepository.Create(foo);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class FooRepository {
    public void CreateFoo(IFoo foo) {
        _logger.Debug("Some logging in the repository");
    }
}
```

If there are multiple requests to process in parallel, reading the log-files will be a challenge. Some kind of unique id per request would help to keep the requests apart when reading the log-file.

Something like this for example:

```
2023-08-07 08:40:06.3280 DEBUG REQUEST-ID FooController Some logging in the controller
2023-08-07 08:40:06.3281 DEBUG REQUEST-ID FooService    Some logging in the service
2023-08-07 08:40:06.3282 DEBUG REQUEST-ID FooRepository Some logging in the repository
```

Is there a build-in way (or even 3rd-party Nugets) to archieve this? I have found solutions that log the thread id, but that I would prefer some kind of GUID or random string as the thread id could be reused after the thread has been stopped.

Comment: There are far better built-in, standards based ways, that can track requests across multiple services and OSs. Check [ASP.NET Core's support for OpenTelemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/net/getting-started/#aspnet-core). Simply adding the instrumentation and exporter libraries allows ASP.NET Core to emit traces to monitoring services like Jaeger or Elastic, or store them to the console or log files. It can even pass the trace IDs to any outbound requests, allowing tracing a request across multiple services

Comment: I don't have multiple services or systems, I want to log the trace of a request within one (micro)-service

Comment: This should answer u. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52306882/net-core-hook-incoming-request-with-a-request-id-to-outbound-http-requests U will have to create custom middleware. But I would go with @Panagiotis Kanavos answer if is possible for your project.

Comment: @DA that answer no longer applies. It's 5 years old, when the OTEL standard was still in its infancy. ASP.NET Core has built-in support for the standard now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working by using a middleware and a custom serilog enricher.

The middleware creates a new trace-ID and puts it into the response headers:

```cs
public class TraceIdMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public TraceIdMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.TraceIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            
        string id = context.TraceIdentifier;
        context.Response.Headers["X-Trace-Id"] = id;
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

The log enricher reads this trace-ID and sets the `TraceIdentifierPropertyName` property:

```cs
public class TraceIdentifierEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public const string TraceIdentifierPropertyName = "TraceIdentifier";
    public TraceIdentifierEnricher(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        if (httpContext is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var property = propertyFactory.CreateProperty(TraceIdentifierPropertyName, httpContext.TraceIdentifier, false);
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(property);
    }
}
```

Finally, the enricher and the middleware have to be registered in the `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<TraceIdentifierEnricher>();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, serviceProvider, cfg) => {

    var enricher = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TraceIdentifierEnricher>();

    cfg.ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration).Enrich.With(enricher);
});
```

```
app.UseMiddleware<TraceIdMiddleware>();
```

This results in the following:

```
[10:25:45 DBG] [1e142e1b-fa5d-4a07-a8b2-2f09efaa8f43] Some logging in the controller
[10:25:46 DBG] [1e142e1b-fa5d-4a07-a8b2-2f09efaa8f43] Some logging in the service
[10:25:46 DBG] [1e142e1b-fa5d-4a07-a8b2-2f09efaa8f43] Some logging in the repository
```

Here, `1e142e1b-fa5d-4a07-a8b2-2f09efaa8f43` is the randomly generated trace-ID.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to access a unique request identifier from your request. You can try to use HttpContext.TraceIdentifier which is part of the .net framework.

FYI: HttpContext.TraceIdentifier is a property provided by the HttpContext class in ASP.NET Core. It's used to get a unique identifier associated with the current HTTP request. This identifier remains constant for the entire lifetime of the request.

You can access this identifier in your controller.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class YourController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<YourController> _logger;

    public YourController(ILogger<YourController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        // Access HttpContext and retrieve TraceIdentifier
        string traceIdentifier = HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;

        _logger.LogInformation($"Trace Identifier in Controller: {traceIdentifier}");

        // Your controller logic here
        return Ok(new { Message = "Request processed", TraceIdentifier = traceIdentifier });
    }
}
```